# Translating a matlab command to c#

Tags: matlab

Im new to matlab and i having trouble understanding this line of code

```
A((i-1)*nneg+1:i*nneg,:) = 
ones(nneg,1)*temp(i,2:n+1)+
temp(npos+1:npos+nneg,2:n+1);
```

does this mean that ->
 each element in A where x is being varied between :
  `(i-1)*nneg+1` and the upper bound `i*nneg` and for all y, will have assigned 1* .....

`an element from temp or all elements in the range of the y` (temp(i,2:n+1))?

and by the same reasoning one of the range of temp(npos+1:npos+nneg,2:n+1) or all added up?

Comment: Please could you format your question so that it's readable?  Select the code snippets, and click the **{ }** button in the editor.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth sorry hope it is more readable

Comment: I would recommend you to put a breakpoint at that line. When you reach it you can select parts of the line and hit f9 to see what they actually evaluate to. (Can be used on variables or just parts of the expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command updates some horizontal sub-matrix of A

```
A(a:b, :) = some range of rows, and ALL columns = some horizontal sub-matrix of A
A(:, c:d) = some range of columns, and ALL rows = = some vertical sub-matrix of A
```

UPDATE:

Without seeing more of your code, i cant be sure but the syntax suggests that temp(npos+1:npos+nneg,2:n+1) is a matrix, and ones(nneg,1)*temp(i,2:n+1) is offcourse also a matrix of the same size which contains only 1's.

(i-1)*nneg+1 and i*nneg will both be integers, where (i-1)*nneg+1 <= i*nneg. these two integers define a sub-matrix of A  which will have their values updated.

ones(nneg,1) creates a vertical array of ones [1,1,1,1...] with length nneg. this is then multiplies with a horizontal array temp(i,2:n+1) which creates a matrix X. X is added to another matrix temp(npos+1:npos+nneg,2:n+1), and the sub-matrix of A (explained above) is updated with this result.

Comment: therefore this means that an the respective element from the row temp(i,2:n+1) will be added to the A's element?